# Searching a name by one of many spell options

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a list of cities, with numerous spelling options for each city (i.e.: New-york, New York City, NY, NYC)

the number of options in not constant and can vary between cities.

for now I have a `cities` table that looks like (dashes, commas etc.. are removed before inserted to the `alternative_names` column:

```
|  id  |     name     |    alternative_names    |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   New-York   |    ny,new york, nyc     |
|  2   |  New Jersey  |  new jersey,jersey,nj   |
```

when the user enters `NYC` or `New Yo` for example - he should get New-York

I can do it with `REGEX` or `LIKE '%query%'`, but the table contains thousands of cities and it will be extremely not efficient.

so - is there a better efficient way to perform this kind of search on a large db?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Consider to normalize your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate `alternative_names` into a new table:

```
city_alternative_names
----------------------
id
city_id
name
```

And query this table to get the "official" city name.

```
SELECT c.name
FROM city c
LEFT JOIN city_alternative_names cn ON c.id=cn.city_id
WHERE cn.name='nyc'
```

Answer (score 1):

See an article on [Multi value attribute](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=hobbies.php) in db design.

Comment: I was hoping to do it without a linking table... seems like there is no other good option, thankyou :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the DB design to have three-column table with only one spelling option per row.  Then you can utilise the database selection.  If your DB looks like this:

```
|  id  | city_id  |   name     |  alternative_names    |
------------------+------------+------------------------
|  1   |      1   | New-York   |  ny                   |
|  2   |      1   | New-York   |  new york             |
|  3   |      1   | New-York   |  nyc                  |
|  5   |      2   | New Jersey |  new jersey           |
|  6   |      2   | New Jersey |  jersey               |
|  6   |      2   | New Jersey |  nj                   |
```

Then you can write a simple search like this:

```
SELECT city_id, name
FROM cities
WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER($1)
OR LOWER(alternative_name) = LOWER($1)
```

Or, even better, split them into two tables CITIES (id, name) and ALT_CITIES (city_id, alt_name) and JOIN on query.